# Memory issue while running ARIMA model

Tags: python, memory, time-series, arima

I am trying to run my ARIMA model and am getting the below error:-

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 52.4 GiB for an array with shape (83873, 83873) and data type 
float64
```

My python/anaconda is installed in the C drive and has somewhere around 110GB free space but still am getting this error. How do I resolve this?

Also below is my code:-

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
model=ARIMA(df['Sales'],order=(1,0,1))
model_fit=model.fit()
```

I tried to slice the dataframe for only 1 year of values, but still having issues.

Anaconda version is 3.8- 64 bit.

My dataframe looks like this-

[image]

It has somewhere around 83,873 rows.

Comment: You're trying to allocate 52gb into memory, not your hard disk... Can you share a sample of the DataFrame?

Comment: I assume that you added a column as a row, therefore you now have as many columns as rows which makes your dataframe too large. Please share a sample of your data right before you train your model.

Comment: I have provided a snapshot of the data frame.

Comment: @ArneDecker are you suggesting me to kinda have individual columns for different years? (The year ranges from 1964-1969)

Comment: "array with shape (83873, 83873)" means that you have 83873 rows with 83873 columns. Your data should only have one column, somehow it has ~84k and that could be the reason why ARIMA needs so much memory during training. This can happen when you add a column as a row by mistake. That is why I would like to know how you preprocess/transform your data.

Comment: Hi Arne, I have 2 columns Month and sales, in total the data frame has 83873 rows and 2 columns. While using Arima, I encountered with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a pivot transformation and it solved my issue.